# adonisjs nested forloop (Lucid relationships)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question about getting the values in a nested object in a `forloop` from Lucid Relationships in `adonisjs`. I am very new to `adonisjs` and `nodejs`.

Look at the code below. This is the source:

```
const products = yield Products
    .query()
    .with('ToProductImages')
```

These are getting pushed into a cart session later on.

This is the result of the following const:

```
    [ { id: 1,
      price: 33.95,
      collections_id: 1,
      ToProductImages:
       [ { id: 1,
           price: 33.95,
           collections_id: 1,
           _pivot_product_id: 1,
           _pivot_image_id: 1 } ] } ],
```

After passing items into the view, this is the forloop i made.

```
    <div class="col s12 m12">
        <table>
            {% for key1,value in cartlist %}
                <li>{{ key1.id }}</li>
                {% for key2,value in key1.ToProductImages %}
                    <li>{{ key2.id }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
```

The output is that the first `forloop` works correctly, The id's are showing up without problem.

The second `forloop` doesn't work at all. I don't know either how to debug the `Key.ToProductImages` as I think its impossible in the view.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, could you give your current output? It is not clear what it is that doesn't work.
Second; When I look at your forloops I notice three things that might have something to do with your issue:

- In the first for-loop you provide 'key1' for the key-values and 'value' for the value-content connected with that key.
  If I understand correctly, it means that your cart contains products and that each product is value. You then call 'id' and ToProductImages.
- In the second for-loop you provide 'key2' for the key-values and 'value' for the value-content connected with the key within the ToProductImages.
  I do not know adonisjs but normally if you give values the same name in the same for-loop you will overwrite the previous one. so key1-value is now the value of key2-value.
- You also give the array key1.ToProductImages as base, but key1 only contains the key (1, 2, 3 for example) and not the values. The same for key1.id, etc.

Try this:

```
    <div class="col s12 m12">
    <table>
        {% for key1,value1 in cartlist %}
            <li>{{ value1.id }}</li>
            {% for key2,value2 in value1.ToProductImages %}
                <li>{{ value2.id }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```